# Visual Studio Code adding Microsoft.EntitiyFrameworkCore.dll

Tags: visual-studio-code

unfortunately the PC I am working with has no Internet Connection and only Visual Studio Code. So far I have not been able to install the microsoft.entityframeworkcore.3.1.4.nupkg package. So I was thinking about just using the dll but keep everything else in the project like usual.

In my class I want to call:

```
using Microsoft.EntitiyFrameworkCore;
```

my csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
    <HintPath>..\Framework\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</Project>
```

I also copied the dll to the debug and release folder, as well as the Framework folder. Can someone give me a hint what I am missing? I assume locally add the nupkg package just by a command line without internet and without the full version of Visual Studio is impossible.

Thanks

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

I think I forgot the itemgroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <HintPath>\Framework\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
 </ItemGroup>
```